# Missing php_soap.dll in Ubuntu 16

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, soap, composer-php

I am trying install composer on Ubuntu 16.

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

and receiving warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading 1.2.0...
Composer successfully installed to: //composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
```

I instaled soap using:

```
sudo apt-get install php-soap
```

in `/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll` directory really there is no such e file

after `php -i | grep -i soap` :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini,
soap
Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400
```

How to resolve problem with `php_soap.dll` ?

Comment: Are you using a Windows or Linux machine?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 16 as I mentioned in subject.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. If you're using Linux, why would you have .dll files for PHP modules? As far as I know the extension of the modules is .so... Did you copy-paste configuration rules from any website?

Comment: It's a good question. I have no idea. I've just tried install composer on Ubuntu and pasted info appeared in my console window.

Comment: Please search for `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`, open it and search for `soap.ini` and let us know if you find it.
Check also `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/`and look for a file called `20-soap.ini`

Comment: In `php.ini` not `exists soap.ini`. Should I type it ? `20-soap.ini` exists in `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121886/discussion-between-tomasz-and-anatoli).

Comment: Let me know if you still need help here or in the chat

Comment: I think this error is triggering because of some strange process. I haven't changed my php.ini manually just upgrades Apache and libraries. But I am also get the same error message exactly as '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First try to search where is the .dll file mentioned with the following command

```
grep -r "soap.dll" /etc/php/7.0/cli/
```

If you get any matches from the command, search for a `;` before them. If they don't have it, open the file(s) and comment the lines e.

```
nano /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
```

Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to invoke the search, then paste the string you're searching for, in this case `soap.dll` and you should reach the line of that string. Put a <kbd>;</kbd> in front of it and save the file with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Try running `php -i | grep -i soap` and to see if you still get any errors.

Comment: I gave a up vote, but just wanted to tell you that the save command should be ctrl + x, followed by y and enter.

Answer (score -1):

Run this two commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

it will fix php package issue.